# Is there any alternative for Axis TCPMonitor plugin?

Tags: http, intellij-idea, tcp

I installed IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 and I want to install the Axis TCP Monitor Plugin on it, but when I searched in the plugins, it didn't give any results, and when I saw it on the Intellij website, it said:

> Not compatible with the version of your running IDE (IntelliJ IDEA
> 2021.3).

Now, is there an alternative for this plugin? Or is there a way to install this plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [TunnelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/155-tunnellij/) plug-in.

Comment: can you introduce a tutorial? I don't know how to use it

Comment: Looks like its not supporting latest IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Community Edition).